# Get coordinates using on_click and ipwidgets on Plotly

Tags: python, onclick, plotly, widget

I'm trying to get the coordinates in a list type when clicking some point of the graph. I have this sample code that I got here in stackoverflow, but I'm not able to print the list or access it out of the call-back function, how can I do it?

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
from pathlib import Path
import json

x = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=50)
y = np.sin(x)
clicked = []

# construct figure that has holders for points, interpolated line and final lines
fig = go.FigureWidget(
    [
        go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode="markers", name="base_points"),
    ]
)
fig.update_layout(template="simple_white")

out = widgets.Output(layout={"border": "1px solid black"})
out.append_stdout("Output appended with append_stdout\n")

# create our callback function
@out.capture()
def base_click(trace, points, selector):
    global clicked
    clicked.append(points.__dict__)

fig.data[0].on_click(base_click)

widgets.HBox([fig, out])
```

I want to access the list clicked and use the data, but I can't access it nor print it on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to use `points` object as follows:

```
@out.capture()
def base_click(trace, points, selector):
    global clicked
    clicked.append([points.xs[0],points.ys[0]])

print(clicked)  #<--- outside the function base_click
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think that I know what to do now.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't make it work. I don't know if the call-back function is never called, but whenever I click the graph, it doesn't print anything at all. I put the print in a try except block because when initializing the program it says that clicked wasn't defined.  I put another print inside the call-back function to see if it initializes, but apparently not. I don't know what may be causing this.

Comment: @Raxhacks Try to put the print(clicked) inside the callback in the last line, it works with me, as well.

Comment: @Raxhacks , I want to ask you, do you want to add the clicked points to the sidebar on the right of the plot?

Comment: sorry I just saw the response. No I don't want to add the clicked points to the side bar, my plan is to get the values of the point to plot a vertical line in that coordinate. Another thing is that I already tried putting the print inside of the call-back and at the last line but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Raxhacks I used Jupyter notebook, what type of IDE are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249168/discussion-between-raxhacks-and-hamzah).

Comment: I think where's the problem. Reading https://plotly.com/python/click-events/ it says: Note: Callbacks will only be triggered when the trace belongs to a
    instance of plotly.graph_objs.FigureWidget and it is displayed in an
    ipywidget context. Callbacks will not be triggered on figures
    that are displayed using plot/iplot.
My code uses plotly.offline.plot, i don't know if this is the main problem.